# Quotient Mappings for Vector Spaces and for Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Below are screencaps of notes from an online Abstract Algebra course. The notes are talking about mappings from a vector space to a quotient one.

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

If I understand the notes correctly, Part 1 is saying that the quotient vector space $V/W$ is a subspace of $V$, for all subspaces $W$ of $V$. Part 2 goes on to say that this isn't true for a general group.

But the nonexample that Part 2 gives doesn't make sense to me. Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/ 4\mathbb{Z}$, and $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. $H \triangleleft
 G$, so $G/H$ is a group of order 2. Thus, $G/H \cong H$, so $G/H$ is a subgroup of G. What I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a better understanding of what **IS** is.

First of all, your understanding of part 1 is incorrect. It does not say that $V/W$ is a subspace of $W$. There's a lot missing in those notes, so let me fill in a few details.

Let $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ be the given basis for the subspace $W$. One then extends that to a basis for $V$ by adding in more basis vectors denoted $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, and so altogether we get a basis $\{w_1,...,w_m,v_1,...,v_n\}$ for the vector space $V$. What part 1 says is that the quotient map $f : V \to V/W$ takes $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ to a basis $\{f(v_1),...,f(v_n)\}$ for the quotient space $V/W$.

What Part 1 probably is also trying to say in addition (although again the notes are deficient on this point) is that $f$ restricts to a vector space isomorphism from $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ to $V/W$. This does indeed give a subspace of $V$ which is *isomorphic to* $V/W$, namely the subspace $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. But you may *not* conclude from this that the quotient space $V/W$ **IS** a subspace of $V$.

*Two mathematical objects which are isomorphic are not "the same" object.*

Regarding part 2, you are again wrong that $G/H$ **IS** a subgroup of $G$. But your observation can be correctly reworded: $G/H$ is indeed *isomorphic to* a subgroup of $G$.

But that's not the real point of the example in part 2. What happens in part 2 is that there does not exist any subgroup $K < G$ such that the restriction to $K$ of the quotient map $G \mapsto G/H$ is an isomorphism from $K$ to $G/H$.

Comment: What does "f restricts to a vector space isomorphism from Span{v1,...,vn} to V/W" mean?

Comment: Do you know what a restriction map is? $f$ is a function with domain $V$ and range $V/W$. Also, $\operatorname{Span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a subset of $V$. Therefore the restriction of $f$ to that subset is a function from $\operatorname{Span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ to $V/W$.

Comment: Furthermore, $\operatorname{Span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a subspace of $V$ so it is a vector space in its own right. Also, $V/W$ is a vector space in its own right. So, what that sentence means is that the restriction of $f$ is an isomorphism from the vector space $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ to the vector space $V/W$.

Comment: Thanks! Why is this property that you mention in the last paragraph about the restriction to K important?

Comment: That's an interesting issue, but perhaps you might like to pose it in a separate question so that the whole math.stackexchange community can see it (it's generally a bad idea on stackexchange to bury new questions in the comments of the answers of old questions). For now I'll simply say that the property that I am mentioning is not something I made up, instead is simply the property that your notes are alluding too.